# Specify class attribute of password box in Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html, razor

Does anybody know how to specify class html attribute of password box in Razor?

Here is what I currently have but it throws errors:

```
@Html.PasswordFor(x => x.Password, new { id="pbPassword", class="loginPassword" })
```

Thanks

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`class` is a keyword to declare a new class in C#. So you must add `@` in this case.

Try this:

```
@Html.PasswordFor(x => x.Password, new { id="pbPassword", @class="loginPassword" })
```

Answer (score 4):

Class is a reserved word so you need to prepend it with an "@" to distinguish it from the reserved word, e.g.

```
@Html.PasswordFor(x => x.Password, new { id="pbPassword", @class="loginPassword" })
```